# What is the Best Way to Keep Digestive Biscuits Fresh

Tags: biscuits, freshness

I bought a bunch of biscuit packets (ginger nut, digestives, bourbon biscuits) and couldn't resist opening a pack or two to try them. Now I'm afraid they'll go stale if I just leave them half opened. I have Tupperware but not super airtight or high quality. Nor do I have any dedicated biscuit tins. Should I keep them in the packet or transfer them somewhere? Can I use a glass pickle jar?

What is the best way to keep biscuits fresh? Any tips on making a DIY tin?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking along the right lines. Airtight is what you're aiming for. Old fashioned biscuit tins were probably less airtight than a lot of modern plastic boxes anyway, so just use the smallest tupperware box you can fit them in (all types in together is fine). I'd leave them in their wrappers, but it doesn't matter.

If you don't have any container at all, they keep for a few days with the end of the wrapper twisted round and clipped shut; that's enough of a seal.

Comment: I found a Tupperware shaped like the IKEA jamka. It closes ok, but I'd have to layer biscuits in, does it matter if there's a lot of space at the top and I don't fill it to the brim? Also, are empty jam jars (wiped clean) or pickle jars ok enough to store? Or would a Tupperware be better? Also I saw some trick where you put a paper towel and some dry rice at the bottom. Worth a try?

Comment: The paper towel and rice might be a good idea in humid conditions if you eat them slowly, but isn't normally necessary. Anything that keeps the moisture out will work. Jars would have to be well washed - I'd be reluctant to use a jar from something strongly and incompatibly flavoured as the smell can stay in the lid seal evert after washing. In my house the way to make biscuits keep longer is to hide them from me!

Comment: You don't have to fill to the brim, and of course if you did that would change when you ate some

Comment: would an old jam jar be airtight enough?

Comment: Yes, probably more so than many plastic containers

Answer (score 1):

A traditional method, used by my mother, which seems to be quite effective is to add a few sugar cubes in to a container with the biscuits.

The sugar absorbs some of the moisture there by extending the life of your biscuits.
This however is only effective if you are using an air tight container.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ChrisH for the most part - air-tight is the way to go.

The only additional concern is that bourbon biscuits contain a filling which is usually some sort of chocolate icing. This releases a little bit of water which can make other biscuits soften fairly quickly, so I would store those separately if possible.